# Every second postback on chrome is slow

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, postback

i've recognized that on google chrome browser every second postback of my asp.net application is a bit slow (~1 seconds)... every other shows up immediately. internet explorer is doing fine on every postback!

someone any idea?

regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that when you are debuging your asp.net app using google chrome that it is running slow?

I had this problem also at one point and was to do with your host file. See this post here for a solution to his problem

https://superuser.com/questions/43823/google-chrome-is-slow-to-localhost

Comment: yes i'm debugging it. but why does iexplore do not bring up the same behaviour? i will check your link

Comment: i can't believe my eyes! this helps!:) thank you. too bad cannot vote up :/

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed that chrome frequently has connection issues, not just during debugging.  I've seen this on multiple machines, different OS's.  Sometimes if we just leave chrome idle for about a minute or two it will completely not respond when trying to do a post back.

After seeing the quality of a number of google's other products this appears par for the course.

Answer (score -1):

Bring up the console to see if there's any weird stuff going on there.  Also, view the Network tab.

Comment: you mean the output of visual studio? there is nothing special. which network tab do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I meant in Chrome.  Tools => Developer Tools.